# Javascript mapping white space object

Tags: javascript, filter, mapping

I am practicing javascript and filtering/mapping method. I am using node for practicing.I have one csv file, I convert them into json by using `csv-parser` package and then from the json data I want to keep one row and remove all the row and save it as a json file. I want to take only `Variant SKU` object but `Variant SKU` word has gap. So I can't do mapping like  `const filteredData = results.map(i => i.Variant SKU)`. After getting the data I want to in json file to specific folder like this structure `src/data/file.json`. I don't know any right approach.

**After converting them into json it looks like this:**

```
{
    month: '2021-03',
    'Variant SKU': '816035',
    Price: '19.140',
    order_name: '#169052',
    total_sales: '19.140',
    Returns: '0.000',
    'Net quantity': '1',
    'Net sales': '19.140',
    'Returned quantity': '0',
    'Ordered quantity': '1',
    Discounts: '0.000'
  }
```

**This is what I did so Far**

```js
const csv = require('csv-parser')
const fs = require('fs')
const results = [];

fs.createReadStream('sales_2021-03-01_2021-04-11.csv')
  .pipe(csv())
  .on('data', (data) => results.push(data))
  .on('close', () => {
   // const filteredData = results.map(i => i.Variant SKU) // does not work
    const filteredData = results.map(i => i === 'Variant SKU') // return me false
    // Taking only Variant SKU and remove other rows
    console.log(filteredData);
    // After mapping saving as json file

  })
```

**This is my csv file looks like**
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work.

`i['Variant SKU']`